# Perform vector operation

Tags: c++, vector

I'm using the vector container to store an array of doubles. Is there any quick 
way of multiplying each element in my vector by some scalar without using a loop.

For example:

```
  vector<double> Array(10,1);
```

will initialise an array of 10 doubles with initial value 1. To multiply this
array by 0.5 I would write:

```
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<Array.size(); i++) 
     Array[i] = 0.5*Array[i];
```

Is there there another way? I have used valarray which overloads the '*' operator 
so that:

```
     Array = 0.5 * Array;
```

is valid but I'd rather not use valarray as it seems the vector container is a more
standard approach for manipulating arrays.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do this:

```
std::transform(Array.begin(), Array.end(), Array.begin(),
                std::bind2nd(std::multiplies<double>(), 0.5));
```

In response to getting the sum of elements:

```
double sum = std::accumulate(Array.begin(), Array.end(), 0.0);
```

And in response to getting `sqrt`'ing each element:

```
std::transform(Array.begin(), Array.end(), Array.begin(),
                static_cast<double (*)(double)>(std::sqrt));
```

That cast is to select the correct overload.

Comment: Thanks, I assume there a function to get the sum of the elements in a vector?

Comment: @Wawel100: Yup, I've added it. If you found an answer solved your problem, click the check mark on it.

Comment: Thanks! Just one final question: how would I use transform to get the sqrt root of each element?

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::transform:

```
 std::transform(Array.begin(), Array.end(), Array.begin(), std::bind1st(std::multiplies<double>(), 0.5)));
```

Comment: wouldn't that be a loop hidden by stl?

Answer (score 1):

The STL vector itself does not allow elementwise scaling in a single operation.

You could wrap your vector with a decorator which applys a scaling factor. The application of a new factor would be O(1) regardless of the size of the vector. This is comes not for free as the drawbacks are increased complexity and a somewhat larger access per element.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an `std::valarray` as it is a more appropriate choice.

There is a reason why the standard library provides a wide variety of containers.  It permits the developer to use "horses for courses".

The `std::vector` is the simplest container and as such is the best choice for many cases.  However for specific cases, the added functionality of another container type may make that type a better choice.  This may be one such case, where the numerical manipulation of the array members is better handled by the `std::valarray`.

Comment: Well he did say in the question he'd rather not. :)

Comment: I have expanded the answer to address valid criticisms made in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

as i know there is not.

if there is one, probably it encapsulates this loop for you. so i dont think the performance would change.