# square-root and square of vector doubles in C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl, square-root, exponent

I'd like to calculate the square and square-root of a vector of doubles. For example given:

```
 vector<double> Array1(10,2.0); 
 vector<double> Array2(10,2.0); 

 for(unsigned int i=0; i<Array1.size(); i++)
     Array1[i] = sqrt(Array1[i]);

 for(unsigned int i=0; i<Array2.size(); i++)
     Array2[i] = Array2[i] * Array2[i];
```

Is there a way of doing the above using a STL function such as transform? Perhaps 
there is an in-built sqrt function that acts on arrays?

Comment: You could always make a function that takes a vector or pointer and does the desired operation on it. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perform vector operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280541/perform-vector-operation)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Same answer as [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280541/perform-vector-operation)...

```
static inline double computeSquare (double x) { return x*x; }

...

std::transform(Array1.begin(), Array1.end(), Array1.begin(), (double(*)(double)) sqrt);
std::transform(Array2.begin(), Array2.end(), Array2.begin(), computeSquare);
```

(The `(double(*)(double))` cast is to force the `sqrt` function to use the `double` variant — it's an overloaded function. You could use `std::ptr_fun<double, double>(sqrt)` to avoid the cast.)

Comment: Aside question: does `ptr_fun(sqrt<double>)` portably work instead of the ugly cast ? I recall compilers often choke on pointers to `<cmath>` overloaded functions.

Comment: @Alex: `std::ptr_fun<double, double>(sqrt)`, but I don't think it's much prettier.

Comment: There is no template deduction if we use `sqrt<double>` ?

Comment: @Alex: `error: no matching function for call to ‘ptr_fun(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’`. (`sqrt` is overloaded, not templated. I don't even think `sqrt<double>` is valid.)

Answer (score 2):

I *think* the second `transform` can be simplified, I'm just not sure how.

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector<double> Array1(10,2.0); 
vector<double> Array2(10,2.0); 

transform( Array1.begin(), Array1.end(), Array1.begin(), sqrt );
transform( Array2.begin(), Array2.end(), Array2.begin(), Array2.begin(), multiplies<double>() );
```

Comment: I think the 2nd `transform` is simple enough.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler has C++0x support, [KennyTM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291258/square-root-and-square-of-vector-doubles-in-c/3291319#3291319) can be tweaked a little:

```
std::transform(Array1.begin(), Array1.end(), Array1.begin(), [](double f)->double { return f * f; });
```

Or if you're using Boost, you can use Boost::lambda:

```
#include <boost/lambda.hpp>
using namespace boost::lambda;

std::transform(Array1.begin(), Array1.end(), Array1.begin(), _1 * _1);
```